# Protecting server from smtp auth relay attack

Tags: linux, security, smtp, smtp-auth

Server configuration

OS Centos 5.xx

SMTP exim / dovecot

I would like to know how to protect my server from smtp relay attacks.

Currently my server is experiencing smtp relay attack because of which it is sending spam mails i can't get how, i suspect it is smtp auth relay attack.

Sudesh

Answer (score 1):

Check http://wiki.exim.org/FAQ/Policy_controls/Q0742 .  What version of Exim are you using?